# How to route to container app in angular SPA routing

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I am implementing single SPA in angular... I have a container app running on localhost:4200 from where i route to diff apps.. I want a routing from my app1 back to container app...
I have used a routerLink for that

```
<button mat-button class="menu-button">
                <a routerLink="/">Home</a>             
    </button>
```

this  routes it back to container app url (4200) but gives a blank screen. How to reload the container app page.

Adding app-routing file

```
 const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: 'nsrt-app', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: EmptyRouteComponent },
 // {path: '',canActivate: [AuthGuard],component:LandingPageComponent,children:routeChildren,data: { Role: '' }}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My container app only has an index.html file to register the apps.

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Container application</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap">
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "app1": "https://srt-onenet.dal1a.ciocloud.nonprod.intranet.ibm.com/",
          "app2": "http://localhost:4202/main.js",
          "nsrt-app": "http://localhost:4205/main.js",
          "sldb-app": "http://localhost:4207/main.js",
          "nav-bar": "http://localhost:4206/main.js",
          "login": "http://localhost:4208/main.js",
          "single-spa": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/single-spa/5.5.0/system/single-spa.min.js",
          "single-spa-layout": "https://unpkg.com/single-spa-layout@1.0.0-beta.2/dist/system/single-spa-layout.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/single-spa/5.5.0/system/single-spa.min.js"
    as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.1.4/minified.js'></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.10.3/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/import-map-overrides@1.15.1/dist/import-map-overrides.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/system.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/amd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-exports.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-register.min.js"></script>
  <template id="single-spa-layout">
    <single-spa-router>
      <nav class="topnav">
        <application name="nav-bar"></application>
      </nav>
      <div class="main-content">
        <application name="login"></application>
        <route path="app1">
          <application name="app1"></application>
        </route>
        <route path="app2">
          <application name="app2"></application>
        </route>
        <route path="nsrt-app">
          <application name="nsrt-app"></application>
        </route>
        <route path="sldb-app">
          <application name="sldb-app"></application>
        </route>
      </div>
    </single-spa-router>
  </template>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    Promise.all([System.import('single-spa'), System.import('single-spa-layout')]).then(([singleSpa, singleSpaLayout]) => {
      const { constructApplications, constructLayoutEngine, constructRoutes } = singleSpaLayout;
      const { registerApplication, start } = singleSpa;

      const routes = constructRoutes(document.querySelector('#single-spa-layout'));
      const applications = constructApplications({
        routes,
        loadApp({ name }) {
          return System.import(name);
        },
      });
      const layoutEngine = constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications });
      applications.forEach(registerApplication);

      start();
    });
  </script>
  <import-map-overrides-full></import-map-overrides-full>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the app routing file?

Comment: Updated the question with routing file.. I understand that there is no mapping to '/' but the container app just has an index.html file n it

Comment: Can you share routing file of both container and other app?

Comment: Updated the question with index.html